# PHP MVC does not load the css file

Tags: .htaccess

I create a simple page based on the MVC pattern and I have a small problem, and exactly does not load the .CSS file. I have, for example, `localhost/webprogram/works` address and it's work, that is, it loads the .CSS file. The problem is when I add more arguments to the address, for example: `localhost/webprogram/works/simple-code-project` and then it does not load the .CSS file.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(css|js|png|jpg)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I will add that the .css file I keep in the public folder ( public/css/public.css )
How can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide the exact code you’re using.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using relative URL for your CSS link. Either use absolute CSS link (starting with http://localist/...) or use a base tag in the head section of your page head section

```
  <base href="http://Local host/webprogram/works/" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Yes, i using realtive URL ( <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/public.css"> ) I do not understand this base tag, where should I add it? Each Controller has a template attached where is a CSS URL link, in head section. Each separate page downloads this template.

Comment: It needs to be used in the head tag. Check: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_base_tag.htm

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work... console log: `GET https://localhost/public/css/public.css net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

Comment: You are using https on that. Need to use http

Comment: Okey but it still doesn't work, console: `GET http://localhost/public/css/public.css net::ERR_ABORTED`

Comment: Is your public folder directly under your htdocs folder or under your htdocs/webprogram/works folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try the base_url();

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/apps/menu_style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "public" from path and put like this :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/public.css">
```